# No qualifying bean found for `MessagesApi`

Tags: playframework, guice, playframework-2.4

I've injected the `messagesApi` into my controller as [documented](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Migration24#i18n) (Play 2.4.x):

```
@Scope(value = "singleton")
@Component
class MyController @Inject()(val messagesApi: MessagesApi) extends Controller with I18nSupport
```

But on boot getting:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [play.api.i18n.MessagesApi] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend your controller with either `BaseController` or `InjectedController`; so your code will be:

```
class MyController @Inject()(val messagesApi: MessagesApi) extends InjectedController with I18nSupport{}
```

For more details you can look at the Play's [documents](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaDependencyInjection).

Comment: Thanks @Dave but I'm still using 2.4.x ugh, sorry I didn't say above!